# TweetSharp Real-Time Tweet Streaming

Tags: twitter, tweetsharp

Any example on how getting Real-time tweets Streaming with TweetSharp ?

NOTE : i can get the new tweets in realtime but i would have to Pull to refresh . i want to stream that without any need to pull

Answer (score 1):

I haven't used the streaming service, but I'm assuming that if you implement something similar to what's in the [unit tests in the source control project](https://github.com/rheckart/tweetsharp/blob/master/src/TweetSharp.Tests/TwitterServiceTests.cs#L934), it should work. It's all async. The link will put you in the right place in the source code on Github.